# Is it possible to query Gmail messages by timestamp?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Is it possible to search all Gmail messages within a range more granular than the day?

For instance, could I search for all chat messages from 3pm to 5pm on October 4th? How would that look?

Looking at the [Gmail advanced search reference](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) I noticed that they mention the specific times, but do not specify the format, most likely it is not supported, but I thought I would check just in case I was simply entering searches in the wrong format...

> **Example:** after:2004/04/16 before:2004/04/18
>
> **Meaning:** Messages sent between April 16, 2004 and April 18, 2004.*
>
> ***More precisely:** Messages sent after 12:00 AM (or 00:00) April 16, 2004 and before April 18, 2004.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to specify time range with accuracy up to a second, because the search operators after:, before:, newer:, older: *accept Unix timestamps*. Using a tool such as [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/), you can find out that

- 2014-10-04 at 15:00 (using GMT for example) has timestamp 1412434800
- Add two hours (7200 seconds), or use the same tool again: 1412442000

Searching for `after:1412434800 before:1412442000` will return the messages within this 2-hour range.

Since converting to Unix time looks like a chore, I made a [bookmarklet](http://normalhuman.github.io/bookmarklets/#gmail-search-time) that makes this substitution in place.

For example, after typing

> after:2015/07/26 10:00 before:2015/07/27 11:30

in the search box (which would not work as is), invoke the bookmarklet and the string will be replaced by

> after:1437919200 before:1438011000

(The bookmarklet interprets the given timestamps in your local time.)

The page I linked has both the source and a draggable link with the bookmarklet. For completeness, the source code is also posted below.

```
inp = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (i in inp) {
  if (/(after|before|newer|older):/.test(inp[i].value)) {
    str = inp[i].value;
    times = str.match(/\d[\d\/: ]*\d/g);
    for (j in times) {
      if (Date.parse(times[j])) {
        str = str.replace(times[j], Date.parse(times[j])/1000);
      }
    }
    inp[i].value = str;
  } 
}
```

Comment: It seems that `after:UNIXTIMESTAMP` is not working properly...

Comment: @Kunok seems to work to me. could you please elaborate?

Comment: @nakhli Ugh..this is old. But as far as I remember I think I gave it too many int chars as input. I think I had to remove last 3 digits or something like that. Somewhat as this answer above mentions, note example in answer, it has 10 chars, while `Date.now()` would return 13 chars. Something like that. I fixed it and script works ever since then, it's still running 0-24 last 12 months, and probably gonna run for a very long time. Thanks. :P

Comment: 13 characters because it returns milliseconds

Comment: This works on the gmail query search bar as well and is documented in the gmail API docs. You can search by the second
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering

Comment: Thanks. Although it looks like it's not strictly required to use Unix timestamps. The after/before filters appear to work with raw date/time strings, e.g. "2021-4-1". Maybe this changed since the ~5 years since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 9):

The specific times are mentioned in the documentation to show that the "after" operator is inclusive of the date given, while the "before" operator is exclusive of the date. There is no way to use the search box on a more specific time range.

If you are using Google Apps Scripts, you can make your search using the best dates you have. Then you can filter the resulting threads based on Time and other criteria. Example:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search("after:2014/09/01 before:2014/09/02",0,100);
var timeFrom = new Date("2014/09/01 10:00:00").getTime();
var timeTo = new Date("2014/09/01 13:00:00").getTime();

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
  var timeThreadStart = threads[i].getFirstMessageDate().getTime();

  if(timeThreadStart > timeFrom && timeThreadStart < timeTo){
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: NOTE:  "after" operator is inclusive of the date given, while the "before" operator is exclusive of the date!!

Comment: Hi Pyrodogg, can I join with use label ? GmailApp.search

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes you can use labels also in the search criteria. Ex. "after:2019/01/01 before:2019/02/01 label:purchases". If I didn't understand your question, please let me know.